# "Ma che teresa che sei": diffusione di espressioni di questo genere

Tags: regional

Spero di essere on topic, quanto è diffuso il termine "teresa" riferito a una persona? L'ho sentito in alto Piemonte come epiteto sia maschile che femminile, per come l'ho capito indica una persona che fa cose un po' stupide.

Comment: A Roma non l'ho mai sentito.

Comment: Potrebbe essere connesso con “avere la teresina” (cioè “demenza senile”).

Comment: Mai sentito (ho vissuto in Lombardia orientale e Toscana).

Comment: [Qui](http://dialetticon.blogspot.com.es/2009/08/teresina.html?m=1) si afferma che la parola "teresina" ha probabilmente a che vedere con il nome di una leggendaria "locomotiva a vapore di proverbiale lentezza".

Comment: @egreg interessante, però io non l'ho mai sentito invece!

Comment: interessante Charo, peccato la fonte sia un Blog, spero di trovare qualcosa di migliore!

Comment: A Milano non l'ho mai sentito, qui si usa "Gina" col significato di persona non molto sveglia... (però "avere la teresina" mi suona familiare).

Comment: In Veneto si dice "avere la Tesesa"... o meglio "avere la Teresina", per qualcuno che si dimentica le cose.

Comment: @egreg: Immagino si tratti di una variante di ["teresina"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000926.jpg) definito dal *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* come "ragazza semplice e di costumi castigati" oppure "uomo effeminato", con questo esempio di N. Ginzburg: "«Se resti ancora  qui, mi verrà voglia forse di ammazzarti».  «No»,  ha  detto,  e  si è  messa a ridere.  Era un  riso  giovane  e  squillante.  «Non  lo  farai.  Hai  troppo  l’aria  da brava teresina. E non mi fai paura»".

Comment: sono piemontese e non ho mai sentito dire questa frase... Ad ogni modo credo che l'ultima definizione di @Charo sia quella corretta. Hai altre informazioni sul contensto?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Papà, di Lentate s/S, che lavorava all'Alfa, mi diceva "Te set un Teresa", "Fa no el Teresa", quando secondo lui avevo fatto, o stavo per fare, qualcosa di stupido. Edit: me lo diceva spesso!

Comment: @PoldoSbaffini Io prima di venire a Milano abitavo a Limbiate ma non l'espressione non l'avevo mai sentita

Comment: @CarLaTeX Perché eri una bimba assennata…

Comment: @PoldoSbaffini Ahahah

Comment: Vorrei precisare che le espressioni "Sei un/a Teresa", "Non fare il/la Teresa" le ho solo sentite dirette a bambini, e il tono era sempre bonariamente canzonatorio.

Comment: Mentre per gli adulti ho sentito, saltuariamente, usare "Teresott" (Lombardo Occidentale)

Comment: Mai sentito, sempre vissuto tra Napoli e Roma.

Answer (score 0):

Credo sia un riferimento alla "Vispa Teresa" https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_vispa_Teresa_(Sailer)

il personaggio della filastrocca è una bambina irruenta che agisce in modo un poco avventato; l'ho sentito usare anche per indicare una persona frivola (l'intera filastrocca - per bambini - ha un che di frivolo). Non so se è calzante, ma non mi viene in mente altra associazione con 'teresa'.

Comment: Fonte? E comunque non è una risposta alla domanda.

Comment: Non mi viene in mente altra associazione con 'teresa'. Ho editato la risposta perché fosse più completa.

Comment: @Riccardo: Il problema è che la domanda è "quanto è diffuso il termine?".

Comment: [Qui](http://dialetticon.blogspot.com.es/2009/08/teresina.html?m=1) si afferma che la parola "teresina" ha probabilmente a che vedere con il nome di una leggendaria "locomotiva a vapore di proverbiale lentezza".

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi, ma "Teresa" nella poesia non é un´attribuzione come nella frase “Ma che teresa che sei”, e poi non capisco il nesso un pó forzato e senza senso col personaggio della poesia. Secondo treccani >>fare la v. Teresa, di donna già avanti in età, che si veste giovanilmente e affetta modi giovanili<<, non leggo "fare/essere teresa" o simili. Inoltre, cosa ha che fare la poesia con "essere una persona frivola"?????

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi, penso che chi associa "vispa Teresa" a "persona frivola" non ha capito una mazza della poesia, oltre a pensare erroneamente anche, e l´unico motivo che mi viene in mente é che "vispo" non é "frivolo" e tanto meno "Teresa" che risulta nome proprio di persona. O mi sfugge qualcosa?

Comment: @mie e "donna già avanti in età, che si veste giovanilmente e affetta modi giovanili" non è frivola? Per il resto non saprei che dirti... cancella pure la mia risposta se pensi che sia fuorviante. Ammetto che era forzata, ma ripeto non mi veniva in mente altro di collegabile.

Comment: <<e "donna già avanti in età, che si veste giovanilmente e affetta modi giovanili" non è frivola?>> non é frivola secondo i significati degli aggettivi "vispa" e "frivola"...  come si dice al mio paese, "per non mischiare pecore e buoi" cerca una fonte al posto del "l´ho sentito usare", sennó chiunque puö rispondere per sentito usare senza sapere della correttezza dell´uso

Comment: (Ancora una volta: ti imploro, @mle, usa ogni tanto qualche accento non del tutto a casaccio. Adesso anche l'umlaut al posto dell'accento grave? Continuano a sanguinarmi gli occhi, a leggerti... :-) )

Comment: caspita, ho visto ora l´umlaut, come scritto in un altro commento "devo comprare una tastiera italiana e digito correttamente, pardon!"..

Comment: A difesa di Riccardo, penso che esigere fonti per la lingua parlata sia scorretto (meglio se ci sono, ovviamente). Ma forse essendo un po' vago avrebbe calzato meglio come commento?